# Why normal json files don't allow comments where as tsconfig.json allow comment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

We know JSON is a data-only format.
Comments in the form // or /* */, are not allowed in JSON.

But how `tsconfig.json` allow that comment in both formats?

Is there any configuration to allow comments in `JSON` files for `node.js` projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `tsconfig.json` is not parsed as pure JSON by the TypeScript compiler (it uses a more lenient parser, [`parseJsonText`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7e51306d30b72ce474054c3f3047f57d90dca41a/src/compiler/parser.ts#L1189)).

There is no configuration to allow comments **in JSON**, because [JSON doesn't support comments](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

JSON-derived formats such as [JSON5](https://json5.org/) do.